# Android Volley: BasicNetwork.performRequest

Tags: android, network-programming, android-volley, android-recyclerview

In my RecyclerView, only few images load up (7 out of 25), while the others come up with:

> Unexpected response code 505 for

https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/myservicekart/ad8bb992-db86-44b4-ab1e-f3655d52a890__1429954824479__cse lab.jpg

and others, whereas for these images:

https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/myservicekart/11324e62-6a94-4bb5-a5e6-a52d749ac645__1428645326244__logo.jpg

They display fine on RecyclerView.

Comment: Is the link accessible from browser? i find a space in 1429954824479__cse lab.jpg

Comment: An URL may not contain spaces. Try to replace the space with `%20`.

Comment: I'm simply calling the JSON feed, I'm not actually coding the url in the project. The images display fine on the web browser. This is the API: http://myservicekart.com/public/search?search=&pageno=1 . You can see the images that's being called. Only the first 5 and around 3 of the rest display properly.